# Adding Pan Zoom to d3js force directed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am slowly making a workflow designer with d3.js. I am attempting to add the pan/zoom behaviour from the sample. Any ideas on how to get this working? I've had it partially working, very crudely with horrendous jittering, but in my frustration i modified it without saving although it was pretty poor anyway.

WorkFlow in Progress

http://jsfiddle.net/3ckG5/27/

Pan/Zoom example

http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043

Mouse Down

```
  if (!mousedown_node && !mousedown_link) {
    // allow panning if nothing is selected
    svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom"), rescale);
    return;
  }
```

Mouse Up

```
  if (!mousedown_node && !mousedown_link) {
    // allow panning if nothing is selected
    force.start();
    svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom"), null);
    return;
  }
```

Attaching the event

Create the background for the force directed graph.

```
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);
```

Call the behaviour of the zoom function

```
svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", rescale))
    .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mousedown", mousedown)
    .on("mouseup", mouseup);
```

Call back for zoom event

```
// rescale g
function rescale() {
  var trans=d3.event.translate;
  var scale=d3.event.scale;

  svg.attr("transform",
      "translate(" + trans + ")"
      + " scale(" + scale + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that you're translating and scaling your SVG canvas, and really what you want to do is translate and scale a g element that holds your network.

Keep in mind, though, that when you scale that g element, it will scale the stroke-width of every element in it, so you'll want to re-adjust your stroke-width based on the current zoom level (just divide the desired stroke width by the current scale value).

You can see a working pan-and-zoom with force layout that does this here:
http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/9357371

Comment: Thank you for this new example.

Comment: And thanks also for the comprehensive [BOOK](http://www.manning.com/meeks/) you are putting together. I already have my copy :-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example. I've looked into it and saw that something's missing. In the original example of the forced graph you could grab a point and stretch it.

Comment: Sorry - hit enter by mistake, so I continue here.
My solution was to add "stopPropgation()" to the zoom and drag events when clicking on a node.

Here's the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/cxLlvIlmo1Y6vJyPs6N9?p=catalogue